Join values from another list query
I'm using PostgreSQL with Dapper.
My situation that I have 2 tables, GameRating and Game from 2 databases.
First thing I select the most rating game like I have Count and GameId (data type is Guid).
Then at the table Game, I want to order by like Count of the GameId. The data will like
ListGameIdCountResponse { Count = 1, GameId = 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx' }

Then I make the ListGameIdCount into the string like this
var ListGameIdCount = string.Join(',', ListGameIdCountResponse.Select(p => $"('{p.GameId}',{p.Count})").ToList()); 

Example:
ListGameIdCount =  ('xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx',10),('xxxxx-bbbb-xxxx',9)

So the query get trending game will like:
SELECT  g."Name",g."Id"                           
FROM  "Games" g
LEFT JOIN (VALUES {0}) as TrendingGameCount (GameId,Count) 
ON g.""Id"" = TrendingGameCount.GameId ::uuid
ORDER BY TrendingGame.Count DESC

After that I use string.Format to binding the value into query
var queryBinding =  string.format(query,ListGameIdCount);

The problem im facing now after binding the ListGameIdCount into the query it have double quote at the value
Example
LEFT JOIN (VALUES "('xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx',1))" as TrendingGameCount (GameId,Count) 

What I want is
LEFT JOIN (VALUES ('xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx',1)) as TrendingGameCount (GameId,Count) 

I try to replace or trim the double quote before binding data into query but it not work

Can you share the query variable value and how you execute the query via Dapper?

You cannot parameterize queries like that. Parameters aren't just some string substitution. You couldn't run a query like conn.Query("@selectOrDelete FROM mytable WHERE pk = 123", new { @selectOrDelete = "SELECT" }) either. Just use Dapper's native list expansion to do a conn.Query("select ... from games where id in @ids", new {ids = ListGameIdCountResponse.Select(p => p.GameId).ToArray()}); - it is important that @ids does not have (...) around it. Order by can be done client side - you don't need to send an int sequence to a DB to get the DB to order your data

sorry for long time response @flackoverstow . Because the data the response need to Paging so I need to order it on sever

It doesn't make sense to me - if your client side knows what IDs to request, it should request only those. If your client side knows 1000 IDs and has 10 IDs per page and wants page 50 it should orderedList.Skip(49*10).Take(10) and get those 10 ids and order them. No need to send list of 1000 IDs together with an incrementing integer X, to DB so you can do an ORDER BY X OFFSET 490 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
